# Can an Implementing Class of Foo be called as an extending class of Foo?

Tags: java, generics, extends, interface-implementation

This question has been baffling to me; below is an example.

#### interface class:

```
public interface UserInterface{

   public String make_nickname();

}
```

#### implementing class:

```
public class UserInfo implements UserInterface{

   private String name;
   private String nickname;

   public String make_nickName(){
   this.nickname = this.name + "ish";
   return this.nickname;
   }


}
```

That given, I'm calling any instances that implements `UserInterface` like such:

#### some arbitrary function in another remote class:

```
public void showNickName(<T extends UserInterface>T user){
   system.out.println(user.make_nickname());
}
```

`T` is used to denote a (generic) implementing class of `UserInterface`.
But here I called it as `<T exnteds UserInterface>` which as far as I know implies T is an **subclass**(not **implementing class**) of `UserInterface`.
Is this legitimate grammar of calling instances of `UserInfo`?
Somehow above code seems to work for me.

Any feedback would be welcome.

Comment: I suspect the keyword `extends` was used for this to avoid adding another keyword that meant "extends or implements" to the language grammar. Adding keywords is bad for backwards compatibility, because if you use a word that someone has used as a name for a variable/method/class/etc. then their code will stop working in the new version. Backwards compatibility is an explicit goal for Java language changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Java tutorial on bounded type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html):

> In generics context, **extends** is used in a general sense to mean either
>   "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).

Comment: thanks. should have researched more before uploading question. Anyway saved me a lot trouble . Thankyou!